# How to do date difference with previous row date using hiveql?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a date column I need to do date difference with previous row date using hive query?

Answer (score 1):

Below would be the query -

```
select date, datediff(date, prev_date) from (select date, lag(date) over (partition by <colName> order by <Name>) as prev_date from tableName) t1;
```

If you can provide the sample data with tableName Can help you with the exact query

Comment: a sub-query isn't needed..the second argument to `datediff` can be `lag...`.

Comment: Thanks Vijiy and @Vamsi Prabhala. As per vijiy query he is creating new column as prev_date in subquery and then we are doing date difference. I think this helps me thanks a lot